# postfix error message format

Tags: postfix

I am newbie in postfix. My question is where exactly can I find format of response to sender when an error occurred and receiver doesn't get the email. I am interested in format and in address of receiver of message.

Thanks!

Comment: What error message do you get? Where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format is described in the manual (http://www.postfix.org/bounce.5.html) and can be configured as you like.

If you instead mean the log message entries found in you syslog logfiles, then these depend on the recipient's server's answer. They can be anything from "554 Unknown user", "550 5.7.2 Quota exceeded" up to "550 Go away, I don't like your face".

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I don't know why, but there is no such file in my folder postfix

Comment: Something that isn't there can be created. If it is not there, Postfix uses it's built-in default. This is how Postfix (always) works.